# Remove space between sticky menu and the image

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, sticky

I want no space between the sticky menu and the image. What's wrong with my code?
here's the link:
http://liveweave.com/0M2mU9

Many thanks.

Comment: use `.jumbotron h1 { margin-top: 0px; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
.jumbotron h1 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```